# Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined cors

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am building a phonegap app which has a `cors.js` with the following code:

```
describe('cors', function () {
it('passes control to next middleware', function (done) {
  // arrange
  var req, res, next;
  req = fakeRequest();
  res = fakeResponse();
  next = function () {
    done();
  };
```

The error I am getting is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Where do I set the reference to describe?

Comment: looks like you're trying to use mocha or some other testing lib and failed to load it properly.

Comment: I have installed mocha but am still getting this error.

Comment: You're basically saying "mocha doesn't work" and that's just not true.

Comment: I really don't know. I'm new to this part of Phonegap.

Comment: Now I am getting 2 more errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined. Why?

Comment: You haven't provided any code to identify your problem. Your question doesn't reference mocha or phonegap. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

When I had this problem, i solved it by switching the order of the libraries.

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
...
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
... then the tests e.g.
<script src="/js/lib/sync/test/local-test.js"></script>
```

Also I import all of them at the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: My files are all at the end of body.I tried changing the order. I'm still finding the same problem but now it is only in chrome. Works fine in IE and FireFox